# String помогите код не работает для двух слов, "разівввв,", "залшти" где ошибка?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
    let str = "Якщоооо остання літерааа слова входить в це слово декілька разівввв, то залишитииии тільки останнє входженняяяя цієї літери"
           var someString = ""
           
           var someArray: [String] = [String]()
           
           for char in str {
               if char != " " {
                   someString.append(char)
               } else {
                   someArray.append(someString)
            someString = ""
        }
        
    }
    someArray.append(someString)
    
    
    var newWords = [String]()
    
    for word in someArray {
        let lastCharactes = word.last!
        var numberOfCharactes = 0
        for char in word {
            if char == lastCharactes {
                numberOfCharactes += 1
            }
        }
        if numberOfCharactes > 1 {
            var newWord = ""
            for char in word {
                if char != lastCharactes {
                    newWord.append(char)
                
                }
            }
            newWord.append(lastCharactes)
            newWords.append(newWord)
        } else {
            newWords.append(word)
        }
    }
    print(newWords)
```

Comment: Опишите подробнее где возникает ошибка, и что за ошибка возникает в целом

Comment: где запятая не работает цикл